# OCR after Bounding Box detection

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, bounding-box

I am trying to find the frequency at which certain words appear in different books using python. For this purpose I have attempted to find the bounding box around each word.

the input:- https://www.dropbox.com/s/ib74y9wh2vrxlwi/textin.jpg

and the output that I get after performing binarisation and other morphological operations for detecting the bounding boxes:- 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9q4x61dyvstu5ub/textout.png

My question is,
I need to perform ocr using pytesser. My current implementation is quite dirty. I am currently saving each of the bounding box detected into small png files .Then run the code for pytesser separately which loops through each of these small images containing words. This process hogs my system.

Is there some other way round to feed my images(detected by bounding boxes) directly into pytesser without first saving them?

After my code is run, I have a list of 544(here in this example) bounding Boxes like

```
                    [minrow, mincol, maxrow, maxcol].
```

Comment: Why don't you just run OCR on the entire thing, and then split it into words?

Comment: pytesser runs terribly bad in that case. Most of the words that come out from ocr are dishevelled. Moreover the input image snapped is from a book so some tilt is also there on the right side, which cause further distortion of the text if feeded as a whole.

Comment: Ah, ok. It looks like internally Pytesser is creating its own temporary file from what you give it as input, which is weird: https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/source/browse/trunk/pytesser.py . So it seems it ends up making two temporary files for each input. `util.image_to_scratch` looks like the culprit.